# Is there a way to connect Azure Bot Services to locally-hosted bot using Ngrok?

Tags: azure, botframework, ngrok

We are developing a Microsoft Bot Framework bot.  Eventually this will be hosted on a site different from Azure but, as I understand it, the channel will pass through Azure to the remote host. I'd like to test this topology using a locally hosted bot and Ngrok.

I'm able to provide a public URL for the bot using Ngrok, of the form

```
http://ee384838.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000
```

and I'm also able to get a public URL for the Azure of the form

```
https://something.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
```

How do I configure the Azure bot services to direct the messages from the Azure URL to the Ngrok URL?  I can't find anything on the many control panels in Azure Bot Services.  I thought "Channels", but that doesn't seem to be it.

Thanks for any clues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Azure Bot Service, under **Bot management** click on **Settings** you will find **Messaging Endpoint** under configuration

[image]

Comment: Is that the public URL for the azure service?  That is, that's the URL the client would connect to?  If so, what I'm trying to do is route that URL to my Ngrok URL

Comment: The Public azure service URL is not configured from here, it is configured when you are adding channels, it would be something like this https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/xxxxxxx for the facebook channel, meaning facebook will always communicate with that URL. The botframework will route those messages to your messaging enpoint. So when you get a message from Facebook for example, it will pass through **https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/xxxxxxx** and then goes to your Messaging enpoint, that is where you want to include your ngrok URL so you can debug locally